# Como fazer o download de uma imagem pelo AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou criando uma funcionalidade parecida com o anexo do email, em que anexamos arquivos mas se quisermos visualizá-lo para confirmar os arquivos a serem enviados realizamos o download.

É nessa parte que estou tendo o problema

```
function abrirArquivo() {

var decoded = $base64.decode(base64);

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([decoded], {type:"image/png"}));

var link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = url;

link.setAttribute('download', "teste");

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

}
```

Eu uso a função acima que pega o `base64` da imagem que eu quero baixar, converte para binário e passa para o construtor do `Blob`, mas quando o download termina a imagem abre com erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

A solução:

```
function mostrarArquivo(arquivo) {
        Upload.base64DataUrl(arquivo)
            .then(function(response) {
                baixarArquivo("imagem", response);
            });
    }

    function baixarArquivo(nomeArquivo, base64) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', base64);
        element.setAttribute('download', nomeArquivo);
        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A linha link.href = url; está atribuindo diretamente um objeto url a uma propriedade href do elemento link. Isso pode causar problemas, porque a propriedade href normalmente espera uma string representando uma URL.

Considere modificar a linha link.href = url; para link.href = url.toString();.

Ao invés de empregar document.body.appendChild(link);, experimente inserir o link em um elemento que permanece oculto no DOM, por exemplo, um .

Use o atributo data-element="#minhaDiv" na div e adicione a diretiva ng-init="MinhaDiv = false" para inicialmente manter a visibilidade oculta. Em seguida, utilize ng-show="MinhaDiv" no Angular.js para controlar quando essa div deve se tornar visível.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).